# WP_Debug not displaying anything

Tags: wp-config, debug

In `wp-config.php` I have included:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

As I understand, this should display certain information on every page, also if there are no errors. However, nothing has changed. In addition, no file `public_html/debug.log` has been generated...

Any idea how to get into debug mode?

Comment: Check with your hosting. by default php error are set to not be display for security reasons, you can ask them to turn them on, or better yet show you how to do it. Important! dont forget to turn off all php error when going live!

Comment: The file should appear in the `public_html/wp-content` directory.  For the same debug info and lots more, use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constant to output errors to screen is actually

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

`WP_DEBUG_LOG` would generate a debug.log in your *wp-content* directory, not in your site root.

Comment: Thanks, the debug file is indeed there. I'm not sure what "The constant to output errors to screen is". But if I understand correctly, it is a hosting setting that is preventing from debugging info coming up on screen?

Comment: If you add the `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` code I referenced to your wp-config.php, then errors would be output to the page. If there are no errors, you won't see any change. I'm not sure what other "certain information" you are looking for, but https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/ can be useful.

Comment: Oh, I now understand (didn't realize that was an additional line to add)

Comment: This doesn't work either

Answer (score -1):

You can control the setting by changing the following settings:

```
define ('WPLANG', 'da_DK');
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
```

Comment: This does the opposite of what the OP asked for.